# Mongodb java driver get result as string not bson object

Tags: java, mongodb

Is there a way to do a query where only the string is returned and not converted to bson object?

I want to use jsoniter to do the deserialization, but don't know if this can be done using java driver.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the bson object and call `toJson()` on it to get a String that contains the query result in json format. That should allow you to use Jsoniter or Gson to deserialize your query's result.

Example:

```
Document result = collection.find(eq("birthYear", 1990)).first(); // Made up query
String resultJsonString = result.toJson();
```

You can read more about the `toJson()` method in [the MongoDB documentation for the Java DB Driver](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/org/bson/Document.html#toJson--).

Comment: yes I know this function, but If I use .first() I get a parsed object. The Document is already parsed right?

Comment: The `Document` is parsed yes. At the core it is a `Map<String, Object>` that imitates the MongoDB Document style. So it is already deserialized and what you're wanting to do seems a little redundant. But it is possible. Calling `toJson()` on the `Document` will give you a `String` object that represents your document in a serialized format. You can then use that String with some other library to deserialize the data.